# What if i define a character array of X elements and add Y (>X) elements to it?

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

There is the NUL character that is added after every string. 
So if I define a character array of 10 elements and put 6 elements, the 7th element is automatically the null character. (If I'm wrong somewhere please 
correct me.)

So if I make a character array of 3 elements and put 4 letters into it like

```
char array[3]={'h','i','y','a'};
```

and I do not put the NUL character, what happens?
Is the null character added in the last position?
Do I get an error?

I'm so sorry, normally I would simply try running the code but my virtual machine keeps crashing for some reason.

Comment: What language? C?

Comment: [Undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) for C or C++.

Comment: It won't try to add a null character anywhere the way you did it. The only issue is trying to put 4 characters into a 3 character array, and also if you try to use a function (like `printf`) which expect a trailing null character. Note that a length 3 char array only has space for 3 characters, which **includes** the null character, if you have one.

Comment: @Charanor yes, c

Comment: go find online c compiler they are online and free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the C Standard (C11 6.7.9. Initialization) it's a constraint violation that must be diagnosed:

> Constraints
>
> 2 No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being initialized.

For example, gcc and clang will report

```
x.c: In function 'main':
x.c:4:30: warning: excess elements in array initializer
   char array[3]={'h','i','y','a'};
                              ^
x.c:4:30: note: (near initialization for 'array')
```

So what happens, i.e. what code does the compiler generate? In C lingo, violating a constraint is **undefined behavior**, so the answer is: we can't tell. Some compiler might ignore the extra character, some might extend the array dimension. Some might refuse to compile it. Some might create a corrupt program. This is the reason why good programmers steer clear of undefined behavior.

Comment: Is this the clang warning message?

Comment: @SzG It's from gcc 5.4 on FreeBSD. Clang skips the first and the last line of the warning message.

Answer (score 1):

You initialize a 3 byte long buffer with a 4 byte long string literal, w/o terminating zero. GCC does it for you for the 1st 3 bytes, ignores the 4th byte and gives you a warning:

```
warning: initializer-string for array of chars is too long
```

When you `printf` it, you just pass a pointer, in our case the `array` symbol means the start address of the array. `printf` has no idea about its length, it will just happily iterate over bytes in memory until it finds a terminating zero.

So `printf` will print the memory area following your `array`, which is undefined behaviour, as only the compiler knows what it has placed after your array. If you're lucky, there will be a zero byte pretty soon, and `printf` stops before reaching a page of virtual memory it can't read. You end up with `hiy` and some garbage.

If you're not so lucky, `printf` reaches an unreadable page of memory and you die a painful death of segmentation fault.

Just trying to explain what the lawyers mean with undefined behaviour... :)